# DirectorySearcher for multiple Guid

Tags: c#, active-directory, directorysearcher

I have list of Active Directory Users's Guid, I need to load a set of properties of those users for a specific reporting. To do this, if we make a bind for each Guid, then it will be a costly one. Whether with DirectorySearcher, can we provide multiple Guid(say 1000) as filter and load the properties?.

Comment: Just curious, are you able to use anything else other than the GUID to uniquely identify the users? (Ex. `SAMAccountName`, `distinguishedName`)

Comment: @X3074861X Currently I have Guid alone to identify the users.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i don't know how to do it programmatically in C#, but if you would write a raw LDAP query you can decide if multiple arguments are combined by AND or OR. To do this you have to open up a group (using a normal brace `"("`) and define if all elements within the group should be ANDed `"&"` or ORed `"|"`.

Here is an example:

```
(|(msExchMailboxGuid=\AD\26\05\EA\5D\C9LD\696\11\40\21\9BSM)
  (msExchMailboxGuid=i8\162\97\39\B0G\BA\ABR\34\AD\1F\AB\9C)
  (msExchMailboxGuid=\A3\99\AC\3A\2B\E8\82F\AB\19\FF\29h2W\0E))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transform your GUID to octet string and then insert it to ldap filter like so:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(); // your guid value

byte[] byteGuid = guid.ToByteArray();
string octetStr = byteGuid.Aggregate("", (current, b) => current + (@"\" + b.ToString("x2")));
string query = "(&(edsaapoguid=" + octetStr + ")(objectClass=user))";
string path = "LDAP://" + yourDomain.com + "/" + "OU=rootOU,DC=yourDomain,DC=com";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(path, yourDomain + @"\" adminName, password);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, query)
         {
            SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
         };
SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
```